# Accurate pyserial read period

Tags: python, logging, serialization, pyserial

I'm currently trying to communicate with a piece of hardware that is measuring some data.

I have to interact with this hardware via serial. I can get data by sending a `GETDATA` string to the device. My goal is to get data precisely at 1 second. I have a thread reading and a thread writing so they don't block each other.

Currently using this method, I am getting a 1 millisecond increase every few seconds. Is there no way to prevent this from happening or can is there a technique to optimize this further?

```
def _writing(self):
    start_time = 0
    while(self.__running_write):
        current_time = time.time()
        if (current_time - start_time) >= self.interval:
            ser.write("GETDATA\r")
            start_time = current_time

def _reading(self):
    while(self.__running_read):
        data = ser.read(100)
        if data:
            _output = "{0}".format(str(datetime.now()))
            print _output
```

Output:

```
2017-09-08 14:53:44.335000


2017-09-08 14:53:45.335000


2017-09-08 14:53:46.336000


2017-09-08 14:53:47.336000


2017-09-08 14:53:48.337000


2017-09-08 14:53:49.337000


2017-09-08 14:53:50.338000


2017-09-08 14:53:51.338000


2017-09-08 14:53:52.339000


2017-09-08 14:53:53.339000
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all «Everyone lies about time». There is no ideal source of frequency ([Frequency drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_drift)) or 100% precision time ([Clock drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_drift)). The frequency of source device or computer port also not so accurate. Frequency can be affected by delays in I/O hardware level, OS, load on the CPU, HDD interactions...

You can set precise timestamp (do not forget about [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) or maybe [PTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol) or [GPS-based time source](https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/GPS-time.html)) for every data package and correcting timings in data processing stage. Many devices have internal time source (sometimes not so precise also!) to create more accurate timestamps.

But if you really need high-stable frequency of data collecting (if after set the priority of data collection process to maximum and data collecion tool into real-time OS enviroment, stability is not enought) everything that you can to do is a remove or dublicate data package (or part of it) to correct frequency then error will becoming too much. See hostory of [leap second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) for example.